# URL structure with 3 subcategories

Tags: seo, url, site-structure

**I have 1 main category and 1 subcategory and 1 additional "topic" or "area"**:

> **main categories:** news, interview, tutorial
>
> **subcategories e.g. for news**: shopping, entertainment, politics, sport
>   etc.

so if there were only these 2 categories it's easy the url would be:

```
http://example.com/news/shopping
```

and detail page something like:

```
http://example.com/2013/12/17/people-are-buying-more-presents-via-internet
```

But, I need to add **the additional "category" or "area" there**. E.g. continents:

So, I was thinking about:

```
http://example.com/europe/news/shopping
http://example.com/africa/news/shopping
...
```

What do you think about this approach from a SEO perspective? To me it seems logical, but Google may think differently.

Another "problem"is that **some articles are international**. How to solve that? So they need to appear in all categories.

How structure the URL then?

**Would it be counted as a duplicate content?** Because the detail page for these articles would still be the same e.g.:

```
http://example.com/2013/12/17/people-are-buying-more-presents-via-internet
```

Answer (score 3):

Your folder structure looks fine, nothing to worry about there. However, you might not want to go any deeper that that, as research by [moz.org](http://moz.org) says:

> The quantity of subfolders in a URL appears to correlate to rankings. URLs with fewer trailing slashes perform better than those with more. Additionally, search engine representatives have recommended that excessive, subfolders in a URL string may be a signal that the page is very deep in a site’s structure and may be less valuable/worthwhile to crawl, index and rank.
>
> Recommendation: Rewrite the URL to include no more than 3 subfolder
>   levels (4 trailing slashes following the domain name)

In your second question, if the content is only being served on a single URL, then there is no duplicate content to worry about, even if you are linking to the single page from multiple categories.